# Two simultaneous for loops MATLAB or C++

Tags: c++, matlab, for-loop

I'd like to run two dependent non-nested for loops. In essence they are two simultaneous Markov chains, where one loop needs to check a value in the other loop. Is it there a right way to do this? Is there a wrong/inefficient way to avoid?

Imaginary example:

Imagine two people are walking round a room and touching things: I record those things they touch in two separate arrays. Those are my two `Chains` or `for` loops.  That's fine as long as their behaviour is independent. But I'd like to change that and so they will have to react (in real-time) to what the other person is doing. Is this possible to do (surely yes)?

For example, Loop 1 would look something like

```
for k=1:n
    do something

     %check loop 2
     if something is equivalent
          moves=n;
     end        
end
```

NB. Technically it could be done one loop after the other, but I'm looking to run something in real-time if possible.

Comment: You need to give a more concrete example of how the two loops are interacting, in order to get a useful answer.  The solution might be multi-threading, or it might simply be to amalgamate the two pieces of code into a single loop body.

Comment: Why did you decide that *nested* loops were the right way to implement two *simultaneous* chains?

Comment: Are the two loops in different threads? If so, I wouldn't recommend it, because the two threads might start passing each other, leading to problems in some cases. But if they are not in separate threads, you'll need a loop nested in a loop.

Comment: @KerrekSB  The behaviour of Loop 1 depends on Loop2's behaviour and to some extent vice-versa... What would you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: @АлександърАлександров They are separate at the moment, that's what's not satisfying about it.  I don't have truly nested loops.  Do you have an example of what you are referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to construct this as one `for` loop that processes both chains simultaneously.  In pseudocode

```
for k = 1:n
    compute step k of chain 1
    compute step k of chain 2

    deal with interaction between chains
```

You will want to package each chain in a data structure that can be passed to a function, so that you do not have to repeat the "compute step k" code twice with variable names modified.

Worry about parallelizing only if this serial approach is too slow.

Comment: Thanks. This is an interesting way of thinking.  I see what you're getting at.  The chains are individual functions at the moment. Can the function pause after one step, take new values from function 2 and then continue?  Or does it have to be written in one big function do you think?

Comment: Your chain functions should each compute *one step* of the appropriate function, save the result in a data structure, and *return*.  When called again, they pick up where they left off.  The looping all happens in the caller.